# Jquery history, inspect the history stack

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, browser-history, browser-state

Im using this history jquery plugin http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html and im trying to inspect the back stack.

I can call this $.historyCurrentHash to return the current hash, but im trying to figure out how to look one step back in the stack.

if i try calling this $.historyBackStack, but i just get an 'undefined'. anyone got any ideas?

I can see that its not a public variable, but im wondering if i need to modify the library or just call it in a different way

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to look back at non-hash history? Like.. trying to see what the actual last different-URL-page was?

Because the browser does not expose this.

Comment: i know the browser doesn't support this but surely this plug-in is building up its own 'history' stack

Comment: @nickmorss - Dump `$.historyBackStack` to your console and see what's there

Comment: tried this, i get >>> $.historyBackStack.pop()
TypeError: $.historyBackStack is undefined.

Comment: Sounds like the plugin isn't loaded then. On the [demo page](http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html) I get an array. But the plugin itself does seem buggy.. first index or two is always `undefined` in that array.

Comment: hmmm, your accessing the array with what query via the console? pretty sure mine is loading as the demo works

Comment: I'm just typing in `$.historyBackStack` and pressing the return key.